# Creating a polygon layer to fill gaps between other polygon layers in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro, fill, create, gap

I have a series of polygon layers equating to separate land-use types provided to me in ArcGIS Pro, but there are a number of gaps in the dataset which I would like to fill with a separate polygon layer representing another land-use type.

Short of tediously manually drawing in the polygons into the gaps, what is the best way that I can do this?

[image: Example frame of my polygon layers showing gaps with no polygon features. I would like to find a way to fill the gaps with a new polygon layer]

Comment: Union with a huge rectangle larger than the study area, then delete the outer polygon. The remainder are holes in the study area.

Comment: Draw a large polygon enclosing all, erase away your small polygons

Comment: Thankyou - I have tried that, and it has worked.